# Automatically running thread stopped after the application idling for more than 1 hour

Tags: c#

I have a web application which runs on IIS 6.0 and it has a thread that runs on the applicaion startup. That thread will run continously after the application startup with a sleep time of 10 seconds (This will update the application cache from getting the data from DB). But once the application is idle for more than 1 hour this thread is no longer running. Please give me a solution for continously run this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Check the AppPool recycling settings in IIS.  You can set it to never recycle.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i'll change the configuraion and check.

Answer (score 0):

Windows service

Almost the same question as yesterday.

Let the ASP.NET app communicate with the Windows service.